# データベースからログアウトしたら再度入れなくなった

Tags: mysql

SQLで一回ログアウトしたら 既存のデータベースに入れなくなりました

エラーは

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 102
ERROR: 
Can't connect to the server
```

です

Comment: 「既存のデータベースに入れなくなりました」との事ですが、どのようなコマンドでSQLにログインしたのですか？
また、SQLサーバのプロセスは実行中になっていますか？

Comment: はい なっています

Comment: どのようなSQLを実行して、どのようにログアウトされましたか？またその後mysqlに入ろうと試みたコマンドも追記をおねがいします。

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 102

エラーメッセージからネットワークがつながっていないことが考えられます。データベースとの疎通を確認してください。以下、netcatを使ってMySQLのデフォルトポートにアクセスできるか試す例です。

```
# nc -vz x.x.x.x 3306

// 成功した場合以下のようなメッセージ
Ncat: Connected to x.x.x.x:3306.
```